# Effect of bootstrap is abnormal when used in jsp

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

When I use bootstrap in jsp to make navigation, the display is different from it used in html.When I open the chrome developer tools,I can see that the bootstrap is imported normally in the sources.How can I resolve this problem.

home.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><strong>luohao</strong>.net</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#">blog</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#">manual</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="profile navbar-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">sign in</a></li>
            <li><a href="">sign up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "the display is different". How?

Comment: Compared with it in home.html, the style is abnormal.I attempt to upload the picture of the difference but I have not enough reputations.So I am confused about how to display the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I use the different version of bootstrap between home.jsp and home.html.I make a mistake.When I use the same bootstrap then it works normally.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the JSP from a web server.?

You should run a JSP in web server like apache tomacat, you can't run it traditionally by clicking it and opening it in a browser as you have done with the HTML file.

Download and install web server like Apache Tomcat on your local machine. You can do it on any IDE also like eclipse.

To see it step by step, you can go to JSP in [eclipse](http://apekshit.com/t/56/Writing-JSP-in-Eclipse)

Comment: I know what you say but it is not the reason.